# Parameter socketBuffer not present in Tomcat 8.5 Connector configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat9

Parameter "socketBuffer" was present in connector configuration up-till Tomcat 8([Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co2IM.png)). Can you please tell me equivalent parameter in Tomcat 8.5.

- Tomcat 8 Configuration Link: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html
- Tomcat 8.5 Configuration Link: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html